# access <span class="xxx"> text within a <td>

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

New to jquery here. so, please spare! I have the below markup generated by my MVC view. Each  row has 4  elements - id, name, date and links to edit/delete the row. The issue I have is that I'm not able to grab the id when I click on the edit/delete links (doing this using jquery). This id is present inside the  tag with class 'customerId' as shown below. (including my HTML and Jquery)

```js
 $('.EditLink').click(function(e) {
   var id = $(this).closest('td').find('span .customerId').text();
   alert(id);
 });
```

```html
<table id="CustomerTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" data-toolbar="#custTable" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc" data-pagination="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Customer Id</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="nameFormatter">Customer Name</th>
      <th data-field="date" data-sortable="true">Modified Date</th>

      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="customerId">1</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/Customer/Details?customerId=1">TestCompany</a>

      </td>


      <td>
        1/6/2015 11:06:04 AM</td>

      <td>
        <a href="/Customer/Details?customerId=1">Details</a> |
        <a class="EditLink" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a> |
        <a class="DeleteLink" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="customerId">2</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/Customer/Details?customerId=2">Sample Company</a>

      </td>


      <td>
        1/6/2015 11:06:04 AM</td>
      <td>

        <a href="/Customer/Details?customerId=2">Details</a> |
        <a class="EditLink" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a> |
        <a class="DeleteLink" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going far enough up before looking for `.customerId`, otherwise your intention is spot on. Use `.closest('tr')` and you should be fine.

oh and you need `span.customerId` <-- no space!

```
 $('.EditLink').click(function(e) {
   var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.customerId').text();
   alert(id);
 });
```

Comment: Gosh! i didn't know that a single space would cause such grief! Thank you so much :)

Comment: indeed! The space means 'within' so here on SO I can do `$("body .post-tag")` and I will get the 6 post-tags within the body. But if I do `$("body.post-tag")` then I am looking for the body tag *with* the class .post-tag, and nothing is returned. Subtle, but also useful!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to use the `parent()` or `parents()` functions. So if you clicked the edit button, from inside your click callback `$(this).parent()` would select your `<tr>`. So you can from there grab anything else based off this.

Answer (score 0):

Go up to the tr (parents(tr)) and then find the .customerId span
http://jsfiddle.net/cm1p47xb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#CustomerTable').on('click','.EditLink', function(e) {
       var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('span.customerId').text();
       alert(id);
     });
});
```

But, really I would change the generated html to give the edit buttons the information they need and not make you traverse the dom everytime you click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

use delegation:

```
$('#CustomerTable tr').on('click', '.EditLink', function(){
    var id = $(this).find('span.customerId').text()
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/